# How to make a sql statement to show between 2 dates?

Tags: mysql, date, compare

I have table `news` with attributes `display_start_date` and `display_end_date`.

So lets say I want the Christmas articles to start dec 10 and end on dec 25, thats what i've tried to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE display_start_date BETWEEN display_start_date AND display_end_date   
  AND display_end_date > NOW() 
ORDER BY display_start_date DESC 
LIMIT $max;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE now() BETWEEN display_start_date AND display_end_date 
ORDER BY display_start_date DESC 
LIMIT $max
```

Comment: May you have a thousand wishes Thanks

Answer (score 0):

let's say you want articles between  2015-11-15 13:00:00 and  2015-11-20 13:00:00, then you go like:

```
SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE display_start_date BETWEEN ' 2015-11-15 13:00:00' AND  '2015-11-20 13:00:00'
AND display_end_date > NOW() 
ORDER BY display_start_date DESC LIMIT $max";
```

you should provide what's in the BETWEEN argument. Because display_start_date and display_end_date are, AFAIU, fields in your table.

The database converts the strings automagically to dates